# Printing only files with previous day’s date in Python

Tags: python

new to Python. The below prints yesterday’s date (in this case 08132018):

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(1)
print yesterday.strftime(‘%m%d%Y’)
```

There’s a directory of files generated daily, with the previous day’s date in the file name.

```
import glob2
import os

array = (glob2.glob(“C:/somewhere/*.txt”))

for line in array
      print line
```

This prints all txt files in that directory, but I only want txt files with the previous day’s date in the name. I’m a bit unsure how to merge the top part (date) I posted with the bottom.

Example file names:

```
labels08132018
clothli08132018
jonathan08122018
exam08092018
```

I would only want the top two to print.

Comment: you mean, all you want is to check if the file name is a date?

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure your indentation and syntax is correct, but IIUC, the following will work for you, simply by adding an `if` condition to your for loop:

```
for line in array:
    if yesterday.strftime('%m%d%Y') in line:
        print(line)
```

More efficient, so you don't have to use `strftime` at every iteration, would be to convert `yesterday` first:

```
yesterday = (date.today() - timedelta(1)).strftime('%m%d%Y')

for line in array:
    if yesterday in line:
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

simply add into your 'glob' statement like so

```
glob2.glob('C:/somewhere/*08132018*.txt')
```

or if you want it to be more general can use %s to enter instead

```
files = 'C:/somewhere/*%s*.txt' %(yesterday.strftime(‘%m%d%Y’))
glob2.glob(files)
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is unclear, but I assume all you want is to check that if the filename contains a date.
So, I'll write a regex for that, forgive me if it's over-engineered.

```
import re

pattern = r'(\d{1,12})(\d{1,31})(\d{0001,2018})'
array = ['not_supposed_to_match','labels08132018', 'clothli08132018','jonathan08122018','exam08092018']
matched_files = []
for line in array:
    match = re.search(pattern, line)
    if match != None:
        matched_files.append(line)
print(matched_files)
```

Hope this answers your question.